# Regex to find words that start with a specific character

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find words starts with a specific character like:

> Lorem ipsum #text Second lorem ipsum.
>   How #are You. It's  ok. Done.
>   Something #else now.

I need to get all words starts with "#". so my expected results are #text, #are, #else

Any ideas?

Comment: You tagged this with c# and javascript.  Where are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Search for:

- something that is not a word character then
- #
- some word characters

So try this:

```
/(?<!\w)#\w+/
```

Or in C# it would look like this:

```
string s = "Lorem ipsum #text Second lorem ipsum. How #are You. It's ok. Done. Something #else now.";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<!\w)#\w+"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
#text
#are
#else
```

Comment: Ah good catch... The word boundary won't work before the #, will it?  But in javascript you can't do negative-lookbehinds can you?

Comment: Note: this breaks will not work in JavaScript running in Safari, cause as of now Safari doesn't support lookbehind https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind (will probably change very soon)

Comment: Instead you can simply use a word boundary: `\B\#\w+`

Answer (score 14):

Try this `#(\S+)\s?`

Comment: This will return "#word " instead of "#word". The \s? isn't necessary

Comment: @zincorp thats why there is a `()` grab group 1

Comment: And what if the `#` is in the middle of a word? Like `abc#de`.

Comment: @vyrp if i have to guess it would match #de.

Comment: @Peter do you know how to make sure it doesn't match abc#de?

Comment: @Peter do you know how to make sure it doesn't match abc#de?

Answer (score 4):

Match a word starting with # after a white space or the beginning of a line.  The last word boundary in not necessary depending on your usage.

```
/(?:^|\s)\#(\w+)\b/
```

The parentheses will capture your word in a group.  Now, it depends on the language how you apply this regex.

The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

Code below should solve the case.

- `/\$(\w)+/g` Searches for words that starts with `$`
- `/#(\w)+/g` Searches for words that starts with `#`

The answer `/(?<!\w)#\w+/` given by Mark Bayers throws a warning like below on `RegExr.com` website

```
"(?<!" The "negative lookbehind" feature may not be supported in all browsers.
```

the warning can be fixed by changing it to `(?!\w)@\w+` by removing `>`

Answer (score 0):

To accommodate different languages I have this (PCRE/PHP):

```
'~(?<!\p{Latin})#(\p{Latin}+)~u'
```

or

```
$language = 'ex. get form value';
'~(?<!\p{' . $language . '})#(\p{' . $language . '}+)~u'
```

or to cycle through multiple scripts

```
$languages = $languageArray;

$replacePattern = [];

foreach ($languages as $language) {

  $replacePattern[] = '~(?<!\p{' . $language . '})#(\p{' . $language . '}+)~u';

}

$replacement = '<html>$1</html>';

$replaceText = preg_replace($replacePattern, $replacement, $text);
```

`\w` works great, but as far as I've seen is only for Latin script.

Switch `Latin` for `Cyrillic` or `Phoenician` in the above example.

The above example does not work for 'RTL' scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `\B\#\w+`

Word boundary, followed by the character, followed by one or more word characters.