# Filter a string for words that starts with a "?" and put them in a <span> - PHP

Tags: php, string

What I wanna do is filter a string like this one:

```
"?group This is a title"
```

And then output something like this:

```
<span class="group">group</span> This is a title
```

My question offcourse is: Is this possible with PHP? And how could I do something like this?

Comment: Ah you need a regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678666/regex-to-find-words-that-start-with-a-specific-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$text = preg_replace('/\?(\w+)/', '<span class="$1">$1</span>', $text);
```

Comment: Ahh yours is shorter!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = preg_replace('/\?(\w+)/', '<span class="$1">$1</span>', $text);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) But it's not quite right yet. Now I get this output: <span class="g">g</span>roup This is a title

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
$string = "wordt bla shit happends and this wil be ?fat and ?this";

$array = array();

// Wanna search on other characters change the second ? and not the first. The first ? is part of the syntax.
preg_match_all('/(?<!\w)\?\w+/', $string, $array);

$result = $array[0];
foreach($result as $value){
    $word = ltrim($value,'?');
    // in your case change the html to whatever you want
    $string = str_replace($value,"<b>$word</b>",$string);
}

echo $string;
```

result will be:

```
wordt bla shit happends and this wil be <b>fat</b> and <b>this</b>
```