# Regex Grouping, multiple groups with delimiter

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am practicing regular expressions and am using Visual Basic.

Here is an example string

```
Dim example = "HelloWorld this! is! a! example!"
```

HelloWorld is the first match, if HelloWorld does not exist the overall matching should fail. The group matching I want, if HelloWorld is present, is four matches of `this! is! a! example!`, so I should be left with the below (ignoring the delimiter `!`)

```
Match 1) This Match 2) is Match 3) a Match 4) example 

HelloWorld ([a-z]+)!*
```

Searching stackoverflow brought me to this link, but I could not modify it to suit my needs.

[Regex to find words that start with a specific character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678666/regex-to-find-words-that-start-with-a-specific-character)

Answer (score 0):

You can capture multiple values in a group using Group's [Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

In c# it would be like

```
string regex="HelloWorld( [a-z]+!)*";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
if (match.Success) 
{
    foreach (Capture capture in match.Groups[1].Captures) 
    {
               Console.WriteLine(capture.Value.Trim(new char[]{'!',' '}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, works wonders except it captures the !     HelloWorld( [a-z]+)!* only captures this

Comment: @SamJohnson you can remove it with `Trim` function

Comment: Thanks for the right nudge, i tested it in regex buddy and got a warning which lead me to read this article http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

HelloWorld(( [a-z]+)!)

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html), the final expression without using trim (.NET methods):

```
 HelloWorld(( [a-z]+)!)*
```