# iOS regex matching non-whitespace characters up to first non-word character after @ symbol

Tags: ios, regex, xcode, tagging, nsregularexpression

I am having a hard time getting my regular expression to work. I am writing an app that does tagging in the comments section, so everytime there is an @ symbol I need to look at the following text to make a link out of it. I.e. what Instagram and Twitter do.

Below is my regular expression, i need to get all occurrances of the regular expression that fits these criteria: @ followed by any alphanumeric character and end when it gets to a space or another @ symbol.

```
 NSString *searchedString = cellComment.commentText;
 NSRange   searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [searchedString length]);
 NSString *pattern = @"@.+[^\s]";
 NSError  *error = nil;

 NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: pattern options:0 error:&error];
 NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:searchedString options:0 range: searchedRange];
 for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches) {
      NSString* matchText = [searchedString substringWithRange:[match range]];
      for(int i = 0; i< match.numberOfRanges;i++)
      {
           NSRange group1 = [match rangeAtIndex:i];
           NSLog(@"group1: %@%lu", [searchedString substringWithRange:group1],group1.location);
      }

 }
```

Comment: Try `@"@\\S+"`. Or `@"@\\S+\\b"`. For Twitter, `@\\w+` should do.

Comment: You should rollback to the post version where you showed your regex.

Comment: I rolled back to the first version because otherwise it does sound as a duplicate of [*Regex to find words that start with a specific character*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678666/regex-to-find-words-that-start-with-a-specific-character). The issue is not that OP does not know the pattern for a `@`+something but the usage of shorthand character classes and a way to match non-whitespace characters up to the first non-word character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had `[^\s]` in your initial post version and the issue is that the backslashes must be doubled in Objective-C regex patterns. Also, `.+` matches *one or more characters other than a newline*, which is not what you need.

You can use

```
NSString *pattern = @"\\B@\\w\\S*\\b";
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pD7bN7/1), it matches

- `\B` - a non-word boundary (there must be no word character before `@`, remove if you need to match in such contexts)
- `@` - a literal `@`
- `\w` - an alphanumeric character (use `\p{L}` if the first one should be a letter, or `[\p{L}\d]` if you want to allow a letter or digit in the initial position)
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace characters up to...
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Note that Twitter usernames follow this pattern:

```
NSString *pattern = @"@\\w+";
```

The `\w+` matches any alphanumeric characters (one or more occurrences).

See the [IDEONE demo of your code](https://ideone.com/HKjVOM)

Comment: You are a lifesaver. used the last one and it works like a charm!

Comment: Just in case you need to make sure the `@...` appears *after* a *non-word* character (i.e. as a whole word), you can use `@"\\B@\\S+\\b"`.